# How to disable brackets auto closing in light table?

Tags: clojure, lighttable

I start to use Light Table IDE for Clojure programming , but I can not find way to disable brackets auto closing. I suppose that something must be added to the *user.behaviors* file but I can not find what exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be disabled in the user.keymap file. By default you have a map entry for adding keymappings (:+). To remove keymappings you need to add one for removing keymappings (:-). Something like this:

> :- {:app {}
>
> ```
> :editor.keys.normal {
>                      "[" [(:editor.open-pair "[")]
>                      "{" [(:editor.open-pair "{")]
>                      }
>
>
> }
> ```

Add more lines for other behaviours you would like to remove (open-pair, close-pair ...). Look in default.keymap to see what has been set up in :editor.keys.normal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, but I suspect the auto-paren behavior is actually implemented by CodeMirror, not Light Table *per se*. Maybe you'd have better luck searching for an option there?

If you find something, you might be able to enable it in Light Table by using the `set-codemirror-flags` behavior.